# Wordpress / Apache Permissions

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I have Apache and wordpress installed on my ubuntu,
everytime I try to upload a widget or anything,
I get an error...

Tried using..

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /var/www*
```

but still nothing..
Any Advice?

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/09. Is its parent
>   directory writable by the server?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem,

'www-data' is the user which performs the file operations here. Assigning proper permissions for www-data can solve the problem.

Try this :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/directory/
```

in your case -

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

I was using nginx on ubuntu 14.04 , I hope this works for apache too.
and `chmod 777` is dangerous ,avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

- Never ever do ...

  ```
  sudo chmod 777 /var/www*
  ```

  It is a security risk. Basically you include "the outside world" (3rd 7) to have access to that directory. Make sure to restore the permissions to 775 for directories and 664 for files.

---

- Make sure the directories you have set up from /var/www/ and deeper to be owned by the user and the group set in apache.
- If they are different: add the user you set up in Apache to the same group as the user that needs to create the files from wordpress.

That way you will have permisions to create files without the whole world capable of putting files onn your system.

---

The command to add a user to an existing group is

```
usermod -a -G {group} {user}
```

---

Regarding `wp-content/uploads/2014/09`:

- Are you sure it is this and not `./wp-content/uploads/2014/09`. It could also be that there is a configuration problem related to the webroot since I would assume the notice to contain a relative path (`./`) or an absolute path (being `/var/www/wp-content/uploads/2014/09`)

Comment: any idea how to 
restore the permissions to 775 for directories and 664 for files properly ?

Comment: here is an example: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/chmod-775-to-only-the-directories-and-chmod-664-to-only-the-files-587544/#post2904514 BEFORE the commands do a `cd /var/www` and then execute the 2 commands.

Comment: I'm still lost.. I never used groups before.. what group should my account be on to access apache freely ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your `error.log` content? That can give the precise error.

**Always keep in mind NEVER to give a `chmod 777` permission to you files!**

That's gonna be a fatal lesson of security for you.

---

Wordpress needs a proper `read - write` permission to work. To make sure everythings fine, try this:

Go to you `public_html` folder and run the commands

```
chown www-data:www-data  -R *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

**After that, you might wanna tighten your security,** [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress)

If you want to make changes, just do what you did above, then tighten your security once more.

**Hope this helps!**

-Dave

Comment: @ItachiSama tell me if it works or not and I would be happy to help